# NodeMCU upload timing out when SPI device attached

Tags: spi, arduino-ide, nodemcu

I am having an issue and looking for some ideas on what could be causing this problem.

I have a NodeMCU 1.0 that works fine and I am able to upload sketches using the Arduino IDE but if I have a SPI device plugged in, sketches will not upload. If I unplugged the device (I'm using pins GPIO 12-15 on the MCU) and then try to upload it works just fine.

As I've been troubleshooting this issue, I did notice that GPIO pins 13 and 15 are marked as RXD2 and TXD2 also so maybe that is related to my problem?

I would just keep working and unplug the device when I need to upload a new sketch but silly me just soldered in the SPI device and I really don't want to have to redo all my solder work.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The specific error I get when the SPI device is plugged in is:
esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header

Comment: Also, I tried to be clever and see if pulling all the SPI pins down to ground would let the code get uploaded but no luck.

Comment: use some other pin as slave select pin

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working by grounding the select pin I was using, GPIO15. I think it may have something to do with what is mentioned here:
https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap04%20-%20Microcontroller.html

But I don't quite understand why it worked.